# Android - tips on creating slot machine animation

Tags: android, animation, canvas, imageview, android-linearlayout

I want to create an animation like a slot machine, in Android, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I want the animation to look like this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EX-uzP6BdjI (its pretty obvious I guess), but then with 8 bars, and instead of the fruits, I want letters.

Now, I've already got the image of the letters (seperate for each letter, and one for all letters).
But because I want to display the letters in some sort of frame, I need to keep the letters within that frame (just like the example), which seems very hard to me, with one image.

What is the best way to make an animation like this?

The end position (the final letter) will be randomly chosen before the animation starts, and the animation needs to be able to change depending on that letter.

The animation doesn't have to be smooth (it can come to a sudden stop at the ending, instead of a smooth ending), but if it's easy to do, I'd prefer that.

Comment: There is a _Slot Machine_ example in this project here on Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/. You might find something useful there. Good luck.

Comment: I didn't notice the "Source" link at first (I actually already stumbled upon it), thanks hehe, I'll have a look!

Comment: Lol... Happens to the best of us. ;-)

Comment: I had a quick look at the code, and it looks really good. However, I think it is not very suited for animation purposes... I'm more looking for a way to animate images or something. Also, this is for a school assignment, and using something complex like this, is a bit over the top I think. I thank you very much for your suggestion though!

Also, After the animation, I want to set a imageview that you then can drag (and drop) to another view. Which, I think, would also be hard with this thing.

Comment: I can not download source code of this repo buildable on AndroidStudio, Can someone help in this....

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an  animation video of each possible scroll, then randomly choose the outcome and play the corresponding videos. a simple if clause can call the correct video, although if you have many possibilities, you might prefer to use switch case.
If you do so, then you can put together photographs of each predetermined outcome, and use them for your drag and drop imageview.